# Are these Big-O notations correct for simple loop functions (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, big-o

Suppose we have two functions below:

```
def is_prime(x):
    """Take an integer greater than 1 and check if it is a prime number."""
    for i in range(2, int(x**0.5) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def multiply(a, b):
    """Take two integers and compute their product."""
    res = 0
    for i in range(1, b + 1):
        res += a
    return res
```

Is it correct to say that the Big-O notation for `is_prime` is `O(c)` and `multiply` is `O(n)`?

I'm a little confused because I thought that loops are at least `O(n)` in terms of complexity, but with the `is_prime` function, it only takes one input and calculates one result, which I wouldn't think varies with its size? Clarification appreciated to better understand Big-O notation on simple functions.

Comment: the first one is `O(sqrt(x))` second one is `O(n)`

Comment: O(c) and O(n)? How could that be? There are no c or n here.

Comment: Constant time is called O(1), not O(c). O(n) is used for linear time algorithms no matter what variable names the program uses.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: But linear in *what*? `multiply` has two arguments, so it is at least plausible that the complexity depends on *both* inputs. By my calculations, aided by Wolfram Alpha, the worst-case step complexity in terms of primitive arithmetic operations in fixed-width integers in the Random Access Machine model for `multiply` is O(log(`a`**`b` (1)_`b`)), and thus does *indeed* depend on both `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Big O***

For the first loop it is as mentioned in my comment `O(sqrt(x))`, because you are looping over numbers from a certain range to a maximum of `sqrt(x)+c` where c is a constant.

Since your what is inside your loop is not affecting the looping procedure, therefore, the time complexity stays the same.

Similarly for the second one, you are looping from `range(1,b+1)` which is `O(b+1) = O(b)`. The more `b` grows the more your algorithm takes time to achieve its purpose. (`Linearity`).

However, if for example, the loop is affected by anything happening inside the loop, the complexity could change.

***naive example similar to the first loop***

```
b=50
for i in range(1,b):
    if i> b**0.5:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
```

This loop's complexity based on the condition is `O(sqrt(b))`. In other words, don't just read the `for...` line and assume the complexity.

Comment: You haven't defined *what* it is that you are counting. In particular, you are only counting number of iterations of the loop body, but completely ignoring the content of the loop body. `p % q` is O(length(`p`)) = O(log `p`) and `a + b` is O(max(length(`a`), length(`b`))) = O(log max(`a`, `b`)), so for example `is_prime` is actually O(sqrt(x) * log x). There is also a non-trivial cost for allocating `i`, if you want to *really* precise.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to say that the Big-O notation for is_prime is O(c) and
> multiply is O(n)?

No.

Let's take the first *algorithm*.

```
for i in range(2, int(x**0.5) + 1):
```

is executed for `sqrt(x) - 1` times because *for* loop starts with `2`. So complexity is `O(sqrt(x))`.

Let's take the second *algorithm*.

```
for i in range(1, b + 1):
```

is executed for `b` times. So complexity is `O(b)`

Comment: You haven't defined *what* it is that you are counting. In particular, you are only counting number of iterations of the loop body, but completely ignoring the content of the loop body. `p % q` is O(length(`p`)) = O(log `p`) and `a + b` is O(max(length(`a`), length(`b`))) = O(log max(`a`, `b`)), so for example `is_prime` is actually O(sqrt(x) * log x). There is also a non-trivial cost for allocating `i`, if you want to *really* precise.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to say "this is O(n)" without explaining what, *exactly* "n" is and what *exactly* you are counting.

You also need to specify whether you are talking about space complexity, step complexity, or time complexity, and whether you are talking about best case, expected case, average case, amortized worst case, or worst case.

Let's start at the beginning. Typically, we express complexity as a function of the *length* of the input. That is important because here, the inputs are *numbers*, and the *length* of a number is of course not the *value* of the number but rather the *number of digits*. However, as we will see later, it is *in this particular case* actually more convenient to look at the *value* of the number itself. It is perfectly allowed to do this, we just have to *clearly define* what it is that we are talking about.

Also, let's say that we are interested in *step complexity* (not time complexity or space complexity) and that we are interested in the *worst case*.

And lastly, we need to define *what it is that we are counting*, so let's say that we are counting "primitive operations" on fixed-size integers. (Where "primitive operations" are +, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, ~). And we are going to assume that these primitive operations take a finite number of steps, bounded by some constant.

Okay, now that we have defined what we are interested in (worst-case step complexity), what we are counting (primitive operations on fixed-size integers) and what "n" is (the *value* of the input), we can go and have a closer look at the algorithms.

In `is_prime`, the `for` loop iterates over the items of the range from 2 inclusive to floor(sqrt(x)+1) exclusive in the worst case. (The worst case here is that the number `x` is prime.) Therefore, the body of the loop is executed up to floor(sqrt(x)) times.

However, we also need to look at the *content* of the loop body. [The step complexity of the modulo operation `a % b` is O(length(a))](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320420/1937) or O(log_2 a).

So, *in total*, the worst-case step complexity of `is_prime(x)` is O(floor(sqrt(x)) * log_2 x) primitive operations on fixed-size integers, or to simplify a bit O(sqrt(x) * log x).

We can make a similar analysis of `multiply`: the loop is executed `b` times. The loop body consists of an addition. [add(x, y) has a worst-case step complexity of O(length(x + y))](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68053/6729), or O(max(length(x), length(y))), or O(length(max(x, y))), or O(log_2(max(x, y))).

So, at *each* iteration of the loop, the cost is O(log_2(max(`res`, `a`))). Since after the second iteration of the loop `res` is always larger than `a`, we can simplify this to O(log_2(`res`)) or O(log (`a` * `i`)).

So, the total time complexity is O(SUM[log_2(`a` * i) over i from 1 to `b`]), which [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BLog2%5Ba+*+i%5D%2C+%7Bi%2C+1%2C+b%7D%5D) is O(log(`a`<sup>`b`</sup> * Pochhammer[1, `b`])), where the *Pochhammer symbol* is the *rising factorial*.

I don't really know how to simplify this further, unfortunately. What we *can* do is take a step back and just make a worst-case assumption about the loop body: the worst case is the very last iteration, where `res` = (`b`-1) * `a`, and thus the addition takes roughly O(log(`b` * `a`)). Then we can say that `multiply` is O(`b` * log(`b` * `a`)) or O(`b` * (log `b` + log `a`)), and we know that this is *overestimated*.

Note also that there is a *hidden operation* for each iteration of the loop that we completely ignored so far: we need to allocate the number `i`. Allocating the number is O(length(i)) or O(log_2 i). I will leave incorporating this operation as an exercise, but note that for `is_prime`, for example, it also involves the Pochhammer symbol.

Note that it is not particularly surprising that the step complexities are so complex. If you look at [the time complexities of various well-known multiplication algorithms on Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions), for example, you also see results like O(n<sup><sup>log 2k-1</sup>/<sub>log k</sub></sup>) for *k-way Toom-Cook multiplication*, where n is the number of digits of the longer number, and k is a parameter of the algorithm.

Comment: Great Answer. Makes me understand in depth my algorithm complexity for my master thesis. Since it has multiple complex steps (which I have a question about and no one helped so far).
Any idea where to find the complexities of dropping elements from dataframes?